# Oracle SQL Developer Export Issue: Target not writable

Tags: sql, database, oracle, export, citrix

I have SQL Developer on machine. Once while exporting data from database to my local drive, It prompted me to ask whether " you would like to allow the local drive to be writable or not". I accidentally clicked No. From then, I am not able to export any file from database to my local drive. Every time I get an error saying "Save as Target :D is not writable". I couldnt find any solution in the preferences section nor over the internet. I am accessing SQL developer via citrix. I have cleared cache, removed tmp files. Nothing helped. Is anybody facing the same issue? Any idea how to clear defaults? I use Windows 7 environment.

Comment: I am really not sure, since I don't have a local copy of SQL developer installed right now. How about you have a look at the various ***.conf** files in the installation directory. Have a look at - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b28240/install.htm#CIHFCGCD

Comment: do you have access to the roaming profiles directory that Citrix uses to store your appdata files for SQL Developer? If so, try deleting the systemX.Y.Z... folder where X.Y.Z = the version number. FWIW, I have never seen this message before, and that makes me wonder if it's Citrix specific.

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced this issue and googled but no luck. So, I started trying multiple options. Below one worked (exclude the double quotes as slash is lost while posting this update)

```
\\Client\C$\Test.txt
```

Example : `\\Client\C$\Data\Test.txt`

Comment: C$ is an administrative share so this only works if you are an admin.